# Dynamic extent indicator in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, python, arcmap, arcgis-pro, zoom

I'm working on map series in ArcGIS Pro, where I'm generating 5129 maps using fixed layout, though till now I got output which is needed for my project, like using dynamic text but I'm facing one problem in data frame, where I want to show the location of active view in main data frame into another data frame, same as showing state into country map.

The problem is, in data frame I want to show only groups which share some specific relation in attribute, like suppose we have 50 states and we made groups with respect to geographic condition, and only those selected features should be displayed in data frame and one which is active in main data frame needs to be displayed with different color.

Above condition is applicable to 2nd data frame.

[image: Data in MapFrame]

[image]

Edit for clarification

in 3rd image we can see the cluster number '500_ptv-2_02', i want to show in dataframe only the data which follow the condition and not the other values eg. '500_ptv-1_05' and the active feature should be displayed in highlighted form.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem right, you should use page definition on the other data frames.

layer properties >> page query >> select the relevant attribute according which you want the layer to appear

[image]